# understanding dojo hitch with parameters

Tags: dojo

I am trying to understand the below dojo code, but couldn't, can someone help me on this

```
lang.hitch({"window": window, mysource: lang.clone(sourcename)}, function (myst) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dojo hitch set the value of this in your callback function.

```
lang.hitch({"window": window, mysource: lang.clone(sourcename)}, function (myst) {
      //this will equal {"window": window, mysource: lang.clone(sourcename)}
      console.log(this);
});
```

Its the same as using javascripts bind or call function.

```
function(myst){
     //this will be assigned ObjectToBind
     console.log(this);
}.bind(ObjectToBind)
```

Comment: can you explain more about it, about the parameters, what does they mean and stuff like that.